# BASH: Match if pattern found twice on same line of text file

Tags: bash, string-matching

If I've managed to create a file full of lines such as this...

`/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054`

How can I get bash to compare the last 2 * 6 digit numbers e.g. only match if line reads say

`/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620541`

Essentially what I have is a list of paths to virtual tapes on a tapelabs system, and on the same line, what the actual VOL1 tape header label is for that tape.

What I care about is if the label (VOL1) doesn't match the actual virtual tape filename.

I did try with `awk` but must be missing something:

```
echo "/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054" | awk '{ if (substr($1,(length($1)-6)) == substr($2,(length($2)-6))) print "Same"; else print "Different" }'
```

Returns `Different` when I thought it should return `Same`

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the comment from @shelter, I realised I was actually taking one too many characters from the length, therefore `/620054` will never match `1620054`!!

Updated code is:

```
echo "/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054" | awk '{ if (substr($1,(length($1)-5)) == substr($2,(length($2)-5))) print "Same"; else print "Different" }'
```

Comment: take your awk apart, and have it print the values of the various substrings. YOu'll quickly see where your problem is. Good luck.

Comment: Ah, yes, helps if you understand the string positioning, is it zero-relative etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
egrep '([0-9]{6}\>).*\1$' <file>
```

Comment: This would match `/VAULT14/620054_V14/999999 VOL1620054`, and I think this case is not expected.

Comment: However, this works: `egrep '([0-9]{6}\>).*\1'` -- adding the `\>` word anchor

Answer (score 3):

Uses the perl-compatible regular expression `\d{6}\b` to find 6 digits at the end of a word (or end of string)

```
while read line; do
    set -- $(grep -oP '\d{6}\b' <<< "$line")
    if (( $1 == $2 )); then
        echo "same -- $line"
    else
        echo "diff -- $line"
    fi
done << END
/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054
/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620541
END
```

```
same -- /VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054
diff -- /VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620541
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ /([0-9]{6})[\ \t]+VOL[0-9]*([0-9]{6}) ]] && \
        [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]]; then
        echo same:$line
    else
        echo different:$line
    fi
done
```

Save as e.g. `2match`, then `chmod +x 2match`, then run:

```
$ cat vault.txt 
/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054
/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620541
$ ./2match < vault.txt 
same:/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620054
different:/VAULT14/620100_V14/620054 VOL1620541
$
```

The regex is probably a bit more complex than it needs to be - I'm not sure how much flexibility there is in the format of your input lines.

Obviously you can change the echo statements to be whatever you want - I just printed out same/different and the full line for checking.